# How to format the time and date from a string using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a string that outputs **10/15/2013 23:59:59**

I am trying to separate the values to determine the amount of time between them and the current time and date.  Dose anyone know if this is possible in jquery?

Comment: How is the date output by the string generated? Is it from a database, or a javascript Date object?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't really include much date / time related utilities (there's [`$.now()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/) and that's pretty much it). There are many javascript libraries out there however to help with dates, I prefer [datejs](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with pure javascript. The javascript `Date` object can be initialized with a string, and you can preform simple math functions on them.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```
var start = new Date('10/15/2013 23:59:59');
var end = new Date('10/15/2013 22:59:59');
alert(Math.abs(start - end));
// outputs 3600000 which is one hour in milliseconds
```

Edit: If you want to get the current time, you can use `Date.now()` to get the current time, and use that to determine the difference between your time and the current time.

```
var start = new Date('10/15/2013 23:59:59');
var now = Date.now();
alert("Days: " + Math.abs(start - now) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
```

Comment: How would you then translate 14.628713680555554 to days/hours/minutes.

Comment: `Math.abs(start - now)` gives the difference in times in milliseconds. You can divide by 1000 for seconds, or 60000 for seconds, etc...

Comment: Just be very-very careful around with simple math and dates, the whole calendar system with leap years, daytime savings and timezones are out there to get you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date("10/15/2013 23:59:59");
var currentdate = new Date(); //gives current date & time
var diffInMs = date - currentdate; //gives Difference in milliseconds.
```

But I guess, for more complex operations and for much easier syntax, you could use any external library - one of which is ofcourse, [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/)